# представление js function на iPhone Chrom

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, iphone

Если функция определена как

```
function myFunction(){...}
```

то на iPhone Chrom выдает ошибку. Какую - не знаю,т.к. нет возможности посмотреть в консоль. Но выполнение AngularJS прекращается.
Если функция определена как

```
var myFunction = function(){...}
```

То все нормально.

Встречался ли кто-нибудь с такой проблемой и как ее можно обойти,
а то в коде очень много определений первого типа?

Побольше кода в вопрос:
Минимальный работающий код:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newVar = "Its not work";
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        return $scope.newVar = 'Its work';
    };
    $scope.myFunction();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

 <span> Angular 
  <span ng-if="0">не </span>
  работает
 </span>
 <br />
 <span ng-bind="newVar">
  Its not work
 </span>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Этот код будет работать на всех устройствах.
Строка "Angular работает" - демонстрирует, что ангулар в принципе загрузился.
Строка "Its work" демонстрирует, что контроллер отработал верно.

А этот код:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newVar = "Its not work";
    $scope.myFunction = myFunction;
    
    function myFunction() {
        return $scope.newVar = 'Its work';
    };
    $scope.myFunction();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

 <span> Angular 
  <span ng-if="0">не </span>
  работает
 </span>
 <br />
 <span ng-bind="newVar">
  Its not work
 </span>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Сработает на всех устройствах, кроме iPhone
(непосредственно сейчас проверить это не могу, проверю в понедельник и внесу коррективы)

Роману:
Вы правы, и благодарю, что Вы дописали код, который я сократил (подлючение angular etc). То, что Вы написали, будет работать, в т.ч. на iPhone.
Но примененный Вами стиль в этом месте:

```
$scope.myFunction = function() {
    return $scope.newVar = 'Its work';
};
```

Считается не лучшим (как мне казалось). Обычно рекомендуют делать так (долго искать ссылку):

```
$scope.myFunction = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
    return $scope.newVar = 'Its work';
};
```

Но, неожиданно оказалось, что на iPhone это не работает.
Вопрос в том, как это обойти, чтобы не переписывать весь код?

Comment: добавь больше кода в вопрос, по имеющимся данным ничего нельзя сказать

Comment: о, да! теперь все понятно!

Comment: попробуй убрать `"use strict"`

Comment: кроме того, как можно заметить на [примере](http://plnkr.co/edit/CK7eDeO9B9NcE7dOOCdE?p=preview) объявление функции так же работает. Проблема заключается именно в том - где и как происходит объявление, и без предоставления [mcve] воспроизводящего ошибку нельзя сказать где именно поправить

Comment: Благодарю за идею с 'use strict' В понедельник попробую. Раньше не могу, т.к. iPhone не пользуюсь. 
Исправил вопрос. Там, где раньше был укороченный код, вставил "Минимальный работающий код".(также пока не могу проверить его на iPhone) Воспользовался для этого кодом Романа с небольшими поправками. Не минусуйте его сильно, он искренне пытался помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Сработало предложение @Grundy убрать

```
'use strict';
```

Правда, почему-то минимальный пример, как оказалось, работает и с 'use strict',
но основной сайт продемонстрировал четкую зависимость от данной опции.

Решение по конкретным действиям такое:
Доделать код с 'use strict', а потом удалить везде, чтобы на iPhone тоже работало.

Но неужели никто с этим не сталкивался!!!

@Grundy прав:

> SCRIPT1047. В строгом режиме объявления функций не могут располагаться внутри других операторов или блоков.Они могут располагаться только на верхнем уровне или непосредственно внутри тела другой функции.

Comment: Проблема в том, что `use strict` накладывает ограничения на то, где могут объявляться функции, например, нельзя объявить функцию внутри `if`: `if(condition){ function func(){...}}`, но некоторые браузеры проглатывают такие описания, а некоторые нет.

Comment: Поэтому вместо убирания `use strict` можно проверить _где_ и _как_ объявлены неработающие функции. Проблема в них

Comment: В моем живом примере функции объявлялись в блоке try{ } в самом начале скрипта, еще до запуска angular, но после загрузки самого angular и всех требуемых мне библиотек. Angular и библиотеки сами по себе ошибки не вызывают, это проверено. Затем идет определение некоторых переменных и функций (здесь ошибка), затем определение модулей angular, затем config, run и bootstrap. На этом этапе ловится все вышеперечисленное. Но, если загрузить последующие скрипты, то ошибка вновь появляется. После завершения всего кода буду копать дальше.

Comment: вынеси объявление функций из блоков, функции должны располагаться либо без вложенности куда-то. либо напрямую внутри другой функции, баз каких-либо других блоков

Answer (score -1):

боюсь спросить но разве так делают, я только начал учить angular поэтому не уверен что прав но в любом случае я бы написал ваш пример как-то так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

<button ng-click="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
<span ng-bind="newVar"></span>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newVar = "Its not work";
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        return $scope.newVar = 'Its work';
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Это поле для ответов. Когда ваш рейтинг станет достаточным, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к вопросам.

Comment: Denis, я знаю что это поле для ответов, очевидно что ответы пишут в поле ответ. мне всё равно на рейтинг и на комментарии к вопросам я просто написал то как бы это сделал я

Comment: я честно не понимаю что не так с моим ответом, кто-нибудь может внятно объяснить. В вопросе у человека не работает привязка скорее всего из-за того что переменная не записана в скоуп как свойство и функция которая её меняет тоже не записана в скоуп как метод

Comment: @pavel почему не содержится-то? Выглядит как честная попытка решения.

Comment: @Роман там автор вопроса вам ответил прямо в вопросе. Это может пролить свет на возможные недостатки ответа.

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне показолось что лучше бы в комментариях всё обсудить ни один ни другой не  могут комментировать пока ещё, вот и общаются так.

Comment: @pavel в комменатариях - уточнения по вопросу. Попытка решения, даже и не самая удачная, должна быть оформлена как ответ. Ну и автор всегда может переработать и улучшить решение.

Comment: @Роман Ваш ответ исправил недостатки моего вопроса, т.к. я поленился написать код целиком, поэтому совсем бесполезным я Ваш ответ не считаю. Но вопрос состоял несколько в другом. Вы написали: можно сделать так-то. Да, конечно, можно. Но можно и по другому, и на всех приборах/браузерах это работает. Вопрос в том, сталкивался ли кто-то с тем, что function не работает на iPhone, и нет ли способа это обойти, кроме как переписывать весь код.